# finding the matrix $P$ and $Q$ such that $A=P^{-1}D_rQ^{-1}$ for given matrices $D_r$, and $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $$D_r=\left[\begin{matrix} I_r &0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right]$$

And $$A=\left[\begin{matrix} 1&4&0&2\\1&1&15&5\\1&3&5&3\end{matrix}\right]$$

By using fundamental column and row calculations, Iwant to find the matrix $P$ and $Q$ such that $A=P^{-1}D_rQ^{-1}$

please help me finding these matrices. Thank you

Comment: What is $I_r$? What is $r$?